# Firebase configuration not working

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, firebase, swift4

the Firebase configuration is not working even though it is called in the app  delegate method

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
    // Override point for customization after application launch.

    FirebaseApp.configure();

    confic(application: application);

    return true
}
```

I did not had this problem before where my classes were initialised as singletons those particular classes are dependent on Firebase however I decided to instantiate them individually in each view controller instead of using singletons however now I'm getting this issue can anyone help?.

I also tried removing any calls to Firebase from the Appdelegate class and just have `FirebaseApp.configure();`  included in the delegate however this did not help either.

the`confic(application: application);`  method contains all my Firebase  related calls  such as checking if the user has logged in etc.
 I moved in here  as in previous post I read this may help however  it made no difference still getting the same error

**Error message**

> 2018-05-16 16:23:42.201080+0100 Jagdschule Gut Grambow[1983:376501] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'The default FIRApp instance must be configured before the default FIRAuthinstance can be initialized. One way to ensure that is to call `[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) in the App Delegate's `application:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:` (`application(_:didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)` in Swift).'
>   *** First throw call stack:
>   (0x1841cad8c 0x1833845ec 0x1841cac6c 0x1021d8244 0x10213b510 0x1021321e8 0x1021209cc 0x102120b5c 0x18e40dedc 0x18e56f628 0x18e56f7a0 0x18e56f360 0x18e23d2c8 0x18e26b4d0 0x102097890 0x102097940 0x18e40dedc 0x18e56f628 0x18e56f360 0x18e23cf24 0x10216b674 0x10216b728 0x18e40dedc 0x18e56f628 0x18e56f360 0x18e40db84 0x18e40e31c 0x18e56f628 0x18e56f7a0 0x18e56f360 0x18e40ced4 0x18e719d88 0x18e17bfd8 0x18dd99254 0x18dd67550 0x18e397a0c 0x18dd66e4c 0x18dd66ce8 0x18dd65b78 0x18e9fb72c 0x18dd65268 0x18e7e09b8 0x18e92eae8 0x18dd64c88 0x18dd64624 0x18dd6165c 0x18dd613ac 0x1869c8470 0x1869d0d6c 0x103aa9220 0x103ab5850 0x1869fc878 0x1869fc51c 0x1869fcab8 0x184173404 0x184172c2c 0x18417079c 0x184090da8 0x186073020 0x18e07178c 0x102130644 0x183b21fc0)
>   2018-05-16 16:23:42.201344+0100 Jagdschule Gut Grambow[1983:376766] 5.0.0 - [Firebase/Core][I-COR000003] The default Firebase app has not yet been configured. Add `[FIRApp configure];` (`FirebaseApp.configure()` in Swift) to your application initialization. Read more:
>   libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
>   (lldb)